# How do I move this label inside my textarea?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to move the label inside the textarea. How do I do this with CSS?

```
<li id='field_1_9' class='gfield' ><label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_9'>Place this inside the textarea</label><div class='ginput_container'><textarea name='input_9' id='input_1_9' class='textarea medium' tabindex='8'   rows='10' cols='50'></textarea></div></li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1smvym84/

Many thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full example where the label text is removed when you click on the textarea: http://jsfiddle.net/1smvym84/5/

The javascript:

```
var txt = "Place this inside the textarea";

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.textarea').text(txt);

});

$("#input_1_9").focusin(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == txt) {
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
$("#input_1_9").focusout(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).val(txt);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use the placeholder attribute to accomplish this, and for older browsers a polyfill https://github.com/ginader/HTML5-placeholder-polyfill

```
<li id='field_1_9' class='gfield' >
    <div class='ginput_container'>
        <textarea name='input_9' placeholder="Place this inside the textarea" id='input_1_9' class='textarea medium' tabindex='8'   rows='10' cols='50'></textarea>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this *without* using the `placeholder` attribute?

Comment: give this a try http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/default_text_fields_using_simple_jquery_trick.aspx

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this using my existing code?

Comment: if you just want the text inside put the text in between the tags:     `<textarea>Place this inside the textarea</textearea>`

Comment: via jQuery: _$("#input_9").attr("placeholder", "some text");_

Answer (score 1):

updated fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/1smvym84/2/
you can use jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.textarea').text($('.gfield_label').text());

});
```

Comment: Ooooooh. Will test :-D

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as I'd like it to.
I just need the text placed inside. It's duplicated here.

Comment: Just add `$('.gfield_label').remove();` at the end of the function.

Comment: Final question. How do I remove the label when I click on the text?

Answer (score 0):

You may also use a CSS hack:

http://jsfiddle.net/Preben/y1k7uLvr/

```
.gfield_label {position:relative;z-index:2;}
li {list-style:none;}
.ginput_container {margin-top:-20px;position:relative;z-index:1;}
```

This means moving the div container up 20 px, and giving the label a position above the div container in the z-index.

[image]

(Not tested in all browsers.)